# Log on of sql service as LocalSystem

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, winforms

I am struggling in a issue related to windows services.

In my project , I want to change the sql service 'LOG ON AS' Local System using c# code.

Comment: Improved formatting. Please add more details

Comment: When you will open services by writing 'services.msc', you will find the sql service over there. By default it will select 'Network service' for 'Log on as'. I want to select Local sytem account radiobutton by using c# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in C# this way:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments= "/c sc.exe config \"mssql$sqlexpress\" obj= \"localsystem\" password= \"\"";
process.Start();
```

**Note:**

- Pay attention to space after `obj=` and `password=`
- isntead of `mssql$sqlexpress`, use your service name.
- you may need run as administrator.
- If you open the command prompt and run this command, your service account will change to local system account:`sc.exe config "mssql$sqlexpress" obj= "localsystem" password= ""`